# angular-nvd3 change in multibar chart column width

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I use angular-nvd3 library in my angular project.
I need to change column width in "multiBarChart". I tried to change on event "on-ready" but it doesn't work

```
onChartReady(scope, element) {
    const api = scope.api;
    const chart = scope.chart;
    const svg = scope.svg;

    var bars = svg.selectAll("rect.nv-bar");
    bars.attr("width", "200");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code snippet to change the width of the bar in multi bar chart.

groupSpacing property accepts a value between 0 and 1

A value of 0.1 will make the bars very wide. A value of 0.9 will make them narrow.

```
chart.groupSpacing(0.8); // Value must be between 0 & 1
```